# Let $f:\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ be a bijective map of sets. Prove that in the Zariski topology, $f$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Probelm:** Let $f:\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ be a bijective map of sets. Prove that in the Zariski topology, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**My attempt:** Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^1$ be a finite subset, so $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, hence $X$ closed. We take $f^{-1}$ on $X$ then $f^{-1}(X) = \{f^{-1}(x_1),\dots,f^{-1}(x_n)\}$, so $f^{-1}(X)$ is also a finite set implies $f^{-1}(X)$ closed. Q.E.D

Comment: Your argunent only shows that $f$ is continuous, but you are being asked to prove that $f$ is a **homeomorphism**. That is, you ought to show that $f$ is continuous, open and bijective.

Comment: I forgot something in the hypothesis. Sorry

Comment: You still only prove that $f$ is continuous and bijective. You could add one line to say we can apply the same reasoning to $f^{-1}$ to show it is also continuous.

Comment: Beware that this is false if  $\mathbb A^1$ denotes the **scheme**  $\mathbb A^1_k$ (the affine line over the field $k$)  . The bijection $f:\mathbb A^1 _k \to \mathbb A^1_k$ is a homeomorphism if and only if it fixes the generic point $\eta \in \mathbb A^1_k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed sets in the topology are the finite sets. Your bijection takes finite sets to finite sets with the same cardinality.

One way of characterizing what a homeomorphism is, is to say it is a bijection on the level of sets, and on the level of open/closed sets. In other words, if $(X_1, \tau_1)$ and $(X_2, \tau_2)$ are topological spaces, $f: X_1 \to X_2$ is a homeomorphism if it a bijection $X_1 \to X_2$ and also induces bijections on the topologies $f_\#: \tau_1 \to \tau_2$.

With this observation in mind, that $f$ is a bijection handles the first part, and since the topology here is determined by just the set-theoretical data of cardinality (unlike say, a metric topology), we see it also induces a bijection on the topologies, and therefore handles the second part.

In other words, your proof is essentially correct, although it might be made clearer by also applying it in the reverse direction, so as to make it clear that with the usual definition of homeomorphism, the map has a continuous inverse as well.

Comment: Does $f^{-1}(X) = \{f^{-1}(x_1),\dots,f^{-1}(x_n)\}$? I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. It's a bijection, so each of those pre-images is a single element.